# Why am I not able to drop values within columns on pandas using python3?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame (df) with various columns. In this assignment I have to find the difference between summer gold medals and winter gold medals, relative to total medals, for each country using stats about the olympics. 
I must only include countries which have at least one gold medal. I am trying to use dropna() to not include those countries who do not at least have one medal. My current code:

```
def answer_three():
    df['medal_count'] = df['Gold'] - df['Gold.1']
    df['medal_count'].dropna()
    df['medal_dif'] = df['medal_count'] / df['Gold.2']
    df['medal_dif'].dropna()
    return df.head()
print (answer_three())
```

This results in the following output:

```
                 # Summer  Gold  Silver  Bronze  Total  # Winter  Gold.1  \
Afghanistan        13     0       0       2      2         0       0
Algeria            12     5       2       8     15         3       0
Argentina          23    18      24      28     70        18       0
Armenia             5     1       2       9     12         6       0
Australasia         2     3       4       5     12         0       0

             Silver.1  Bronze.1  Total.1  # Games  Gold.2  Silver.2  Bronze.2  \
Afghanistan         0         0        0       13       0         0         2
Algeria             0         0        0       15       5         2         8
Argentina           0         0        0       41      18        24        28
Armenia             0         0        0       11       1         2         9
Australasia         0         0        0        2       3         4         5

             Combined total   ID  medal_count  medal_dif
Afghanistan               2  AFG            0        NaN
Algeria                  15  ALG            5        1.0
Argentina                70  ARG           18        1.0
Armenia                  12  ARM            1        1.0
Australasia              12  ANZ            3        1.0
```

I need to get rid of both the '0' values in "medal_count" and the NaN in "medal_dif".
I am also aware the maths/way I have written the code is probably incorrect to solve the question, but I think I need to start by dropping these values? Any help with any of the above is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `dropna()` is not an inplace operation by default. Should be - `df['medal_count'].dropna(inplace=True)` and `df['medal_dif'].dropna(inplace=True)`

Comment: For clarification, the df is read from file.

Comment: Hi Nickil, I tried that but it results in the exact same output?

Comment: Oh, so you want to drop that particular row from the entire `DF` whenever there is any `NaN` encountered. Just do - `df.dropna(inplace=True)` then. You can't drop `Nans` separately on every series object and expect the `DF` to take care of that. If you are working on series as an independent entity, then it would work giving you the 4 finite rows but not on the entire `DF` as such because it must follow the same index axis after all.

Comment: There are various 0's and NaN's amongst those 2 columns I mentioned. I wish to get rid of all of them, whilst keeping the rest of the data for those columns. If I made a copy of those columns/the data would that make it possible? (Sorry if this is stupid, I'm a bit out of my depth I think!)

Comment: That's exactly what I said before. When you want to view the row as an entirety in a single `DF`, you cannot drop the first row of 2 columns and want to view it's remaining finite values present in other non-removed columns. `DF`'s don't work like that. However, you could replace these `Nans` and 0 values with some dummy value showing that it's irrelevant to maintain uniformity across the entire dataframe.

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep trying stuff :)

Answer (score -1):

You are required to pass an axis e.g. axis=1 into the drop function.
An axis of 0 => row, and 1 => column. 0 seems to be the default.

[image]

As you can see the entire column is dropped for axis =1

Comment: Ok, I tried "df['medal_count'].dropna(axis=0)"  and  "df['medal_dif'].dropna(inplace=True, axis=0)" as I wasn't sure which was correct. Neither change the output.
Trying it with "axis=1" results in the following error: ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: Note - Series objects operate on `axis=0` by default. Supplying `axis=1` on a `DF` would drop that entire column if it contains any `NaNs` in it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Not what I'm after!

Comment: If you want to filter you can use df[df.myColumn >0] -> all NaN will be ignored, and columns <= 0 be filtered.

Comment: Current code:
`def answer_three():

 df['medal_count'] = df['Gold'] - df['Gold.1']

 df['medal_count'] = df[df.medal_count >0]

 df['Gold2'] = df['Gold.2']

 df['Gold2'] = df[df.Gold2 >0]

 df['answer'] = df['medal_count'] / df['Gold2']

 return df['answer']

print (answer_three())`

the result is all 1's though...